# Всплывающая подсказка при наведении на кнопку

Tags: qml

Как реализовать в кнопке на qml всплывающую подсказку.
Хочу чтоб при наводе на копку всплывала название кнопки , а саму напись я скрыл чтоб можно было вывести иконку на внешний вид кнопки.

```
   Button {
            id: button1
            text: qsTr("линия")
            display: AbstractButton.IconOnly

            Image {
                 sourceSize.width: 100
                 sourceSize.height: 40
                 anchors.fill: parent

                 source: "file:/C:/Open_GL/razkroika/linia.jpg"
                 fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }

        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 40
            color: button1.down ? "#ccccff" : "#bde0ff"
            border.color: button1.down ? "#ccccff" : "#bde0ff"
            radius: 2
        }

        onClicked: {
            // пока пусто :3 
        }
    }
```

А вот свойство сплывающей подсказки так что то и не нашёл :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это  "тулл тип" назвается

ToolTip

нашёл документацию (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tooltip.html) а потом всё было как в кино :3

```
Button {
            id: button1
            text: qsTr("линия")
            display: AbstractButton.IconOnly
            // Вот тут :3 
            ToolTip.visible: hovered
            ToolTip.text: qsTr("выкройка") 

            Image {
                 sourceSize.width: 100
                 sourceSize.height: 40
                 anchors.fill: parent

                 source: "file:/C:/Open_GL/razkroika/linia.jpg"
                 fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }

        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 40
            color: button1.down ? "#ccccff" : "#bde0ff"
            border.color: button1.down ? "#ccccff" : "#bde0ff"
            radius: 2
        }

        onClicked: {
            // пока пусто :3 
        }
    }
```